# Shapes manipulation slows down while in "Presenter View" mode

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I'm developing a VSTO plugin for PowerPoint 2013 that updates a self-made chart in realtime, while the presentation is running.

The chart is simply a group of shapes (rectangles, textblock, lines, ...).

When it gets updated, it needs to change the size of some of rectangles, their background colors, some labels, etc... It's usually quick, except if I use the "**Presenter View**" mode, under the Slideshow tab.

[image: Presenter View]

When this option is activated, there is at least one second of delay between each UI manipulation. As I have to update a chart with many entries, it can take around 30 seconds to update all rectangle sizes and labels.

My question : is there any way to prevent the presentation from getting updated, do all my modifications and, when everything is done, let PowerPoint apply the changes to the UI once for all ?

The same problem has been reported here on MSDN forums : [Poor VSTO performance during multiscreen slideshow, PowerPoint 2013](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d1a89633-1a17-4e71-9bb4-bd08964de750/poor-vsto-performance-during-multiscreen-slideshow-powerpoint-2013?forum=officegeneral)

Comment: Do you have the example code that updates the view when the 'Presenter View' is checked?

Comment: Can you dynamically check to see if it's checked? That may be a start in figuring out a way to conditionally handle the processing.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft delivered a partial solution to this issue back in 2015 :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3099951/october-13,-2015,-update-for-office

The kb specific to Powerpoint 2013 can be found here : 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3085564

> When you turn a slide show to the presenter view and then enter some text in a slide in the normal view in PowerPoint 2013, the text is added slowly in the presenter view but not in the normal view. After all the text is entered, it will appear all at once in the normal view.

After further testing, it's not completely solving the issue for my specific scenario.